# CodeIgniter + XDebug: debug only working in the main controller, index() function

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project using NetBeans + XDebug. I cannot debug urls other than the index page. Namely, the XDebug **works correctly** when calling the default controller and index() function.
E.g.:  http://www.my_site_name/
or,    http://www.my_site_name/home/index

It will not work for other urls such as:
http://www.my_site_name/controller_name/about_us
http://www.my_site_name/home/test

This is my configuration:
.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
<FilesMatch "\.(mp4|webm|ogv|woff)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_site/

#www redirection
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,R=301]

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

In my application's config file I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = '/LoadExpress/';
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

In php.ini:

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

I have been trying using the tips seen in other posts, yet I must be missing something. Any help will be appreciated.